# angular replace was not working

Tags: angularjs

a = "It was popularised<br> in the 1960s with<br> the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

```
a.replace(/\n|\t/g,'&lt;br&gt;');
```

All br tags need to replace with `\n\t` but it was not working .

Comment: can you provide your code ?

Comment: There is no newline, nor tab character in your `a` string.

Comment: Do you want to find all new lines and tab characters and replace them with `<br>` or you want to find all `<br>` and replace them with `\n\t`?

Comment: can you please fiddle it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
var myRegex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
alert(a.replace(myRegex, "\n\t"));
```

This should replace every `<br>` tag with `\n\t`. See [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/er8pjwg5/)